# Can't rake db:migrate because of mysql missing .frm file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

**$ rake db:migrate**

```
==  ChangeFriendListToText: migrating -  ======================================
-- change_column(:profiles, :friend_list, :text)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Can't find file: './shadow_development/profiles.frm' (errno: 13)
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:263:in `query'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:263:in `execute'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:413:in `columns'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:598:in `column_for'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:451:in `change_column'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `block in method_missing'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `block in say_with_time'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mechmark.rb:280:in `measure'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:348:in `method_missing'
    db/migrate//20130110234754_change_friend_list_to_text.rb:3:in `up'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `block in migrate'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mechmark.rb:280:in `measure'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ar-octopus-0.3.4/lib/octopus/migration.rb:52:in `migrate_with_octopus'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:365:in `migrate'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:491:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `ddl_transaction'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:490:in `block in migrate'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:477:in `each'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:477:in `migrate'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/tasks/databases.rake:112:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
    /Users/me/sources/shadow/lib/rake_exceptional.rb:7:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

**$ which mysql**

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql
```

**$ ls /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data/shadow_development/profiles.frm**

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data/shadow_development/profiles.frm
```

Using ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0] and Rails 2.3.14 on Mac OS X 10.7.5

**Update:** here is the migration file:

```
class ChangeFriendListToText < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :profiles, :friend_list, :text
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :profiles, :friend_list, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you verified the permissions of the MySQL files?

Comment: thanks, that was the issue (described below)

Answer (score 3):

Turned out it was a permission issue.  Using `chmod` on that file allowed the migration to happen.  The reason the permissions were off is because we recently changed how we launch mysql, so things that were previously created under my account are now created by the user `_mysql`.

To anyone else who experience this problem in the future, use the `ls -l` command to identify permission descrepencies.